# How to set Foreign key with one PK of composite key

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have two tables:

```
class company
{
    prop Id //PK
    prop EskaId //PK
}

class policy
{
    prop Id //PK
    prop CompanyEskaId //FK
}
```

I want to link `CompanyEskaId` with `EskaId` using Fluent API.

I've tried

```
HasRequired(b => b.CompanyObj).WithMany().HasForeignKey(c => c.CompanyEskaId);
```

But in this case how can determine the target PK is EskaId, not the Id

Comment: You **cannot** - if you have a compound PK made up from multiple columns, any FK **must** provide **ALL** columns in the PK - you cannot reference just "half a PK" ....

Comment: For which entity is this Fluent API snippet? Also: there's no `CompanyObj` mentioned in that code to be seen in your entities explanation up top. .....

Comment: it is an example in real code I was added it @marc_s

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/modeling/code-first/data-annotations

Answer (score 0):

In EF6 an Entity has only a single Key so you would have to make `EskaId` the key of `CompanyObj`.

EF Core supports [Alternate Keys](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/keys?tabs=data-annotations#alternate-keys) where an entity has multiple keys and a Foreign Key can refer to any key. eg:

```
internal class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Blog> Blogs { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Post> Posts { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Post>()
            .HasOne(p => p.Blog)
            .WithMany(b => b.Posts)
            .HasForeignKey(p => p.BlogUrl)
            .HasPrincipalKey(b => b.Url);
    }
}
```